# Reconstructing a nilpotent Lie algebra from cohomology

Tags: lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a nilpotent Lie algebra over a field $k$ of characteristic 0. I heard that it is possible to construct a presentation of $\mathfrak{g}$ using $H^1(\mathfrak{g},k)$ and $H^2(\mathfrak{g},k)$.

More specifically, it is well known that
$$H^1(\mathfrak{g},k) := (\mathfrak{g}/[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}])^*.$$
So that we may think of $\mathfrak{g}/[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$ as the free Lie algebra generated by (any basis of) $H_1(\mathfrak{g},k)$. I heard there is some way of uncovering the entire Lie algebra by considering the cup product somehow, could anyone help me understand how this is done? A reference would be helpful as well.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I found a paper of Clair Miller, titled “The Second Homology Group of a Group”, and can be found [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-04/S0002-9939-1952-0049191-5/S0002-9939-1952-0049191-5.pdf).

It has nothing to do with my suggestive question about the adjoint of the cup product, however, it gives an interpretation of $H_2(G,\mathbb{Z})$ for an arbitrary group $G$, in terms of the group of commutator relations in $G$ modulo universal commutator relations. I guess I am still curious as to how to read what commutator is associated to a given cocycle.

Comment: There exist non-isomorphic nilpotent 5-dimensional Lie algebras whose cohomology algebras are isomorphic as graded algebras. So one shouldn't expect to recover the Lie algebra structure from these data without any further information.

Comment: @YCor is this example written down somewhere? I think it is alluded to indirectly in one of your papers but I am not 100% sure (and I would like to be)

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko yes: see p47, line 17 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2229 (arxiv current version v4). One is the standard filiform Lie algebra: basis $e_1\dots e_5$ with $[e_1,e_i]=e_{i+1}$, $i=2,3,4$; the other one having the "additional" bracket $[e_2,e_3]=e_5$.

Comment: @YCor Fantastic, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be a finite-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebra over a field $k$, and $E$ a minimal generating system of $L$. Then it is well-known that the cardinality of $E$ is given by
$$
|E|=\dim H^1(L,K).
$$
Indeed, we know that the cardinality of $E$ is equal to the dimension of the $K$-vector space $(E)_K$ generated by $E$. This maps naturally into $L/[L,L]$. It is easy to see that this mapping is an isomorphism.  On the other hand we have
$$
H^1(L,K)={\rm Hom}_L(L,K)={\rm Hom}_K(L/[L,L],K).
$$
Secondly it is also known by the Hochschild-Serre sequence, that we have, for a minimal relation system $R$ of $L$, that
$$
|R|=\dim H^2(L,K).
$$
This yields some information by generators and relations for $L$ given by the cohomology $H^1(L,K)$ and $H^2(L,K)$ (but not a characterisation).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it suggests that we should view the Lie algebra as a quotient of the free Lie algebra on H^1 using relations coming from H^2. Given a specific element of H^2, how do I find which element of the free Lie algebra on H^1 would be "killed" by that relation? I think this should somehow come up using the cup product.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022404918302743) is helpful. At least, Theorem $1.2$ looks a bit related. The cup-product map $H^1(L,K)\times H^1(L,K)\rightarrow H^2(L,K)$ appears in Theorem $1.1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can reconstruct the whole $\mathfrak{g}$ from its cohomology if you know not only multiplication in it, but the whole $C_{\infty}$-structure.
For a definition of a $C_{\infty}$-algebra, see, for example, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.1655) of Kadeishvili. It is an algebra with a collection of higher multiplications $m_i: A^{\otimes i} \rightarrow A$, which encodes the Chevalley-Eilenberg algebra up to a quasi-isomorphism. If you know raitonal homotopy theory, then perhaps the easiest way to explain how to reconstruct $\mathfrak{g}$ from $H(\mathfrak{g})$ with an $C_{\infty}$ structure is to take the minimal model in the sense of Sullivan of
any commutative dg-algebra which is quasi-isomorphic to $H$. It will be the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex of $\mathfrak{g}$, by the uniqueness of the minimal model.

There is a more canonical way to obtain the same answer if you are willing to assume that $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional. Then it is dual to a *conilpotent* Lie coalgebra $L$, and $C(L)$, the Chevalley-Eilenberg cohomological algebra of $L$ is equal to that of $\mathfrak{g}$. From cobar-bar duality, for conilpotent Lie coalgebra $L$ the bar construction of $C(L)$ (rather, the space of indecomposables in it)
is quasiisomorphic to $L$. From the fact that $C_{\infty}$-quasiisomorphic $C_{\infty}$-algebras have quasi-isomorphic bar constructions, the bar construction of $H$ also calculates $L$.

In down-to-earth terms you can reconstruct $\mathfrak{g}$ as the free Lie algebra generated by $H_1(\mathfrak{g})$ (the first *homology* space)
quotiented out by the relations $m_i^\vee: H_2 \rightarrow H_1^{\otimes i}$  which are dual to the operations of $C_{\infty}$ structures.

It would've been enough to know just the multiplication on $H$ if $C(\mathfrak{g})$ were a *formal* algebra, but Chevalley-Eilenberg algebras of finite dimensional nilpotent Lie algebras are never formal, by [a theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2047375) of Hasegawa.